# 2 span in div, first auto width and overflow hidden, second width is adaptive to text

Tags: html, css, responsive

Here is the demo to describe its shortcomings - https://jsfiddle.net/7t81gour/

```css
.elem{
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 25%; /* adaptive width */
    height: 50px;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.text span:first-child{
    max-width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

.text,
.text span{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"><div class="text"><span>Text text</span><span>0123</span></div></div>

<br>

<div class="elem"><div class="text"><span>Text text text text text text</span><span>0123456</span></div></div>
```

`overflow: hidden` will work in the case that `max-width` (line 18) is set [or any defined width]. The problem is that `max-width` can not be used due of adaptive width of his parents. I will never know the maximum possible width (to display text as much as possible on the same line) of `span:first-child` - and I have to subtract (take into account) the width of `span:last-child` from `max-width`? - No way!

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try using flexbox?

Comment: I tried but I don't know - I can't reach the centered text.

Comment: So you want the text to have ellipsis but the number to always show?

Comment: is this helpful? https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Comment: Its looks like I tried - http://jsfiddle.net/xcnjtyzs/
without text align center :(

Comment: ok, I think I have what you want, I posted it as an answer this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/tomeralmog/rzx7uge5/

```css
.elem{
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 25%; /* adaptive width */
    height: 50px;  
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text span:first-child{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text span:last-child{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <div class="text">
    <span>Text text</span>
    <span>0123</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="elem">
  <div class="text">
    <span>Text text text text text text</span>
    <span>0123456</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this snippet helps?

**Tip:**

- Use `<span></span>` to wrap inline elements.
- us `<div></div>` to wrap block elements.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
}

.elem {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 25%;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.elem:last-child {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="elem">
    <div class="text">
      <span>
      <span>Text text</span><span>0123</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="elem">
    <div class="text">
      <!-- wrap your spans in another <span> 
    or <p> with setting margin and padding to 0 to prevent additional white spaces -->
      <span>
      <span>Text text text text text text text text </span><span>0123456</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `additional white spaces` is need as well, good point - but I need inline solution (one line only)

Comment: Why `flex-grow` is used? `.elem` is separate element - and it's same, you just changed the width to higher number [container is 85%, try f.e. 40%]

Comment: `flex-grow` makes element use all white space left in the container which is a dynamic behavior to keep `elem` next to each other.

Comment: Im a little sure on what is that, just it is not need I'll try to say :), they are not side by side - the main problem is still 2 lines on a low width of the parents.

Comment: @alexso can't help much more. I am sorry